# How to convert `ctime` to `datetime` in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

```
import time
t = time.ctime()
```

For me at the moment, `t` is `'Sat Apr 21 11:58:02 2012'`. I have more data like this.

**My question is:**

- How to convert `t` to `datetime` in Python? Are there any modules to to it?

I tried to make a time `dict` and then convert `t`, but feel like that’s not the best way to do it in Python.

**Details:**

- I have a `ctime` list (like `['Sat Apr 21 11:56:48 2012', 'Sat Apr 21 11:56:48 2012']`).
- I want to convert the contents to `datetime`, then store that in a `db` with `timestamp`.

Comment: Why not just do `from datetime import datetime` `datetime.now()`

Comment: exactly, i have a string: 'Sat Apr 21 11:58:02 2012', and i want to convert it to datetime.

Comment: Converting from strings like that is less than ideal, but this question gets that answer.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior): this function parses a string representing a time according to a format. The return value is a [struct_time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time).

The [format parameter defaults to `%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime) which matches the formatting returned by ctime().

So in your case just try the following line, since the default format is the one from ctime:

```py
import datetime
import time

datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

Returns: `datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 21, 4, 22, 00)`

Comment: I try that way for hours, but still can't convert  'Sat Apr 21 11:58:02 2012' to datetime correctly.

Comment: thank you, it's my fault, I put the wrong parameters.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y') works

Comment: sorry, i don't know how to close my question? may be you can tell me?

Comment: @flreey to the left of each answer to your question, there is a little "V" sign that you can click. When your problem is solved, you usually click on it so other can see the good answer, and you gain a couple reputation points, and the answer that is accepted as well. It is just under the number of votes to the left of each answer. You should do it on all your questions.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `%c`:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(), "%c")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

Try `datetime.strptime()`.

**See:** http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: i've try strptime, but it can't work correctly. So i ask question here

Comment: I mean i can't convert  'Sat Apr 21 11:58:02 2012' to datetime using that method.

Comment: Perhaps try showing us your code where you're attempting to use datetime.strptime(), and show us the incorrect output that your code gives.

Comment: thanks, I using the methond incorrect. datetime.strptime(time.ctime(), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y') work

Answer (score -2):

## Convert the 'time.ctime()' to datetime

`time.ctime()` by default returns a string.  you can just format this as shown in the other answers

```py
import datetime
import time
from time import strptime

# Print the ctime -- Result type is already a string
a = time.ctime()
print("\n\tToday's date: {} Type: {}\n".format(a, type(a)))
print("\n\tToday's date: {} Type: {}\n".format(time.ctime(), type(time.ctime())))

# just convert that to a datetime 
c = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
print("\n\tToday's date: {} Type: {}\n".format(c, type(c)))

# %a - abbreviated weekday name
# %b - abbreviated month name
# %d - day of the month (01 to 31)
# %H - hour, using a 24-hour clock (00 to 23)
# %M - minute
# %S - second
# %Y - year including the century

d = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%c")
print("\n\tToday's date: {} Type: {}\n".format(d, type(d)))

# %c - preferred date and time representation

# Results: 
#     Today's date: Fri Apr 22 15:50:17 2022 Type: <class 'str'>
#     Today's date: Fri Apr 22 15:50:17 2022 Type: <class 'str'>
#     Today's date: 2022-04-22 15:50:17 Type: <class 'datetime.datetime'>
#     Today's date: 2022-04-22 15:50:17 Type: <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

## Convert the raw class from ctime 'time.struct_time' to date time

Something different, if you want to parse the object and convert it back as follows.  Not ideal, just something i found to work different.

```py
import datetime
import time
from time import strptime

# How to Convert the class 'time.struct_time' to date time.
X = strptime(time.ctime(), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
print("\n\tToday's date: {} Type: {}\n".format(X, type(X)))

# Create the Date time String from the ctime format:
date_time_str = "{}-{}-{} {}:{}:{}".format(X.tm_year, X.tm_mon, X.tm_mday, X.tm_hour, X.tm_min, X.tm_sec)
print("\n\tToday's date: {} Type: {}\n".format(date_time_str, type(date_time_str)))

# Convert the Date time String from the datetime format:
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print("\n\tToday's date: {} Type: {}\n".format(date_time_obj, type(date_time_obj)))

# if Needed you can reformat the resulted datetime object:
Y = date_time_obj.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
print("\n\tToday's date: {} Type: {}\n".format(Y, type(Y)))

# Results:
#     Today's date: time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=15, tm_min=49, tm_sec=25, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=112, tm_isdst=-1) Type: <class 'time.struct_time'>
#     Today's date: 2022-4-22 15:49:25 Type: <class 'str'>
#     Today's date: 2022-04-22 15:49:25 Type: <class 'datetime.datetime'>
#     Today's date: Fri Apr 22 15:49:25 2022 Type: <class 'str'>

# From: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm
# Directive
# %a - abbreviated weekday name
# %A - full weekday name
# %b - abbreviated month name
# %B - full month name
# %c - preferred date and time representation
# %C - century number (the year divided by 100, range 00 to 99)
# %d - day of the month (01 to 31)
# %D - same as %m/%d/%y
# %e - day of the month (1 to 31)
# %g - like %G, but without the century
# %G - 4-digit year corresponding to the ISO week number (see %V).
# %h - same as %b
# %H - hour, using a 24-hour clock (00 to 23)
# %I - hour, using a 12-hour clock (01 to 12)
# %j - day of the year (001 to 366)
# %m - month (01 to 12)
# %M - minute
# %n - newline character
# %p - either am or pm according to the given time value
# %r - time in a.m. and p.m. notation
# %R - time in 24 hour notation
# %S - second
# %t - tab character
# %T - current time, equal to %H:%M:%S
# %u - weekday as a number (1 to 7), Monday=1. Warning: In Sun Solaris Sunday=1
# %U - week number of the current year, starting with the first Sunday as the first day of the first week
# %V - The ISO 8601 week number of the current year (01 to 53), where week 1 is the first week that has at least 4 days in the current year, and with Monday as the first day of the week
# %W - week number of the current year, starting with the first Monday as the first day of the first week
# %w - day of the week as a decimal, Sunday=0
# %x - preferred date representation without the time
# %X - preferred time representation without the date
# %y - year without a century (range 00 to 99)
# %Y - year including the century
# %Z or %z - time zone or name or abbreviation
# %% - a literal % character
```

Comment: This is not conveting a ctime object.

Comment: Thanks @Soren I updated my answer.  Have a Great one!