# How to obtain datetime.date and datetime.time from time.ctime() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time

I'm trying to access `time.ctime()` in order to make some simple boolean operations. I found [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256093/how-to-convert-ctime-to-datetime-in-python):

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

Which gives me this:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 5, 17, 7, 51)
```

How can I access `time.ctime()` date and time separate so I could get:

```
datetime.date(2017, 10, 5)
```

and

```
datetime.time(17, 7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) and [`time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) methods to extract them:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 5, 17, 7, 51)
d = dt.date()
t = dt.time()
```